# MySQL JOIN, No Data to Join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm made one Like/Dislike System. Now I want to make active LIKE or DISLIKE option by adding .active css class. For this I must select selected option from MySQL database, but Confessions and Votes aren't at same table and I must use SQL Join.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
    Confessions.ID, Confessions.WriteTitle, Confessions.WriteArea,
    Confessions.POST_DATE, Votes.Type
FROM Confessions INNER JOIN Votes ON Confessions.ID = Votes.PostID 
WHERE ForUser = :ForUser AND Status = :Status AND Votes.IP_Check = :IP_Check
```

This query works well but there is one problem. When someone post something this post don't have any likes/dislikes in table Votes and SQL Query don't sends back post with this ID, but i'm getting back posts with ID that have at least one like.

Now how I can make query sends back fields from Confessions when there no data to join with Votes?

EDIT:

How I can join two tables when record in joined table doesn't exist.
I'm tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Confessions.ID, Confessions.WriteTitle, Confessions.WriteArea,
    Confessions.POST_DATE, Votes.Type
FROM Confessions LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes ON Confessions.ID = Votes.PostID 
WHERE ForUser = :ForUser AND Status = :Status AND Votes.IP_Check = :IP_Check
```

but when record from votes with PostID like ID in Confessions doesn't exist MySQL gives back empty result for this record. isthere any other way?

Comment: you can use exists maybe

Comment: LEFT or RIGHT Join don't work

Comment: "LEFT or RIGHT Join don't work" - and why?

Comment: @Marvin I don't know why don't work. I tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN bot none of this not works well

Comment: Then you need to be more specific. What does your data look like? What is the concrete output you expect and what is the concrete output you're getting?

Comment: I'm getting only data from Confessions for each I have record in Votes. Example: I have one recordin Confessions but i dont have record with same PostID in Votes and query doesn't get back any data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81200/discussion-between-miljan-ilic-and-marvin).